# Regex to find digits group after a text match

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have tried many regex expressions but unable to get the desired output.
My string is

```html
Ms.Evalyn J Hobbs AND Mr.Jan K Hir sch AND Ms.Gale D Bannister 3611
```

I need to extract the digits group which come after Mr or Mrs that is 3611

Comment: Are the numbers always at the end? If so, `/([\d])*$/ should work.

Comment: without re `print(*filter(lambda x: x.isdecimal(), s.split()))`

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?:Ms|Mr|Mrs).*?(\d+)` and get Group 1 value

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDoRBv/2)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to capture digits in a group after Ms., Mr. Ms. (or maybe  Miss.) could be:

[`\bM(?:rs?|s|iss)\.[^\d]+(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/DIVnT9/1)

That would match

- A word boundary `\b` to make sure it is not part of a larger match and then M
- An alternation `(?:rs?|s|iss)\.` that would match one of the variants followed by a dot.
- Match not a digit using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\d]+`
- At the end capture one or more digits in a capturing group `(\d+)`

```js
const regex = /\bM(?:rs?|s|iss)\.[^\d]+(\d+)/g;
const str = "Ms.Evalyn 33 J Hobbs AND Mr.Jan K Hir 55 years Mr. sch AND Ms.Gale D Bannister 3611";
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```